# How to check that a user-input of a list of CellObject-s actually belong to the EvaluationNotebook?

Tags: notebooks, gui-construction, cells, style, stylesheet

Suppose a user inputs a list of `CellObject`-s to operate on. How might one check these objects to determine if they actually belong to the `EvaluationNotebook`? Here is a given sample:

```
cells = Cells[CellStyle->"Input"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this to check whether they all belong there:

```
DeleteDuplicates[ParentNotebook /@ cells] === { EvaluationNotebook[] }
```

Comment: so if i get True they all belong and False otherwise? It's for error checking.

Comment: @JulesManson the key is `ParentNotebook[_CellObject]`, this gives you information about cell's notebook, then you can do whatever you need. I chose this way, it should do the job but feel free to do whatever you wish.

Comment: no, this is perfect. i just didnt expect it to be so easy. thanks again. :)